# Setting state in ComponentDidLoad synchronously

Tags: react-native

I am trying to simply do something such as

```
ComponentDidLoad(){
this.setState({
count: 1
}) 

console.log(this.state.count)

}
```

However, it will always print undefined to the console. Is there any way to do this so that it executes the code synchronously to ensure that the state has been set before console.log is run so it will not return undefined.

COuldn't really find a way to implement a callback.. not sure what to do.. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of componentDidMount ?

Comment: @NaderDabit my bad, I was.. wrote this on the go.. same question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to log the value out in the next process because you're logging out the state before it has had time to be set, and to answer your question about a callback, yes setState has one. Try something like this:

```
ComponentDidLoad(){
  this.setState({
    count: 1
  }, () => {
    console.log(this.state.count) 
  })
}
```

`setState` offers a callback once the state has been set, and this is a good use case, when you need to make sure the state value is there.